# grid items click event not working on small screes like mobile

Tags: javascript, html, css, twitter-bootstrap

I displayed a grid items in a div which is toggled to show and hide the items,
In desktop and tablets it is working good, but in mobile devices the items button click event is not working.
In desktop when i mouse over the grid item it will change its color to blue and cursor to pointer.

sample code of this grid is as follow

```
<div class="items_grid" style="width: 50%; float: right; height: 320px; overflow-x: hidden; overflow-y: auto; position: absolute; z-index: 10; top: 0px; right: 0px; border: 1px solid rgb(219, 219, 219); display: block;">
            <div class="col-md-12 col-sm-12 col-xs-12 div_padding">
                    <div class="form-group col-md-12 col-sm-12 col-xs-12" style="background-color:#DADADA;color:#000000;border:1px solid #DADADA;">
                    <center><form class="form-inline" style="padding:0px;margin-bottom:1px;">
                        <select class="form-control" name="menucategory" onchange="getbycategory(this.value)">
                        <option value="0">--Select Category/All--</option>
                        <option value="1">ABC</option>
                        </select>
                    </form></center>
                    </div>
                </div>
                <div id="menu_items">
                <div class="col-md-2 col-sm-3 col-xs-6 itm">
                <button class="btn btn-primary itm_btn" id="itmname" onclick="insertitem('1527')">Comma Hoox Powerbank 6000</button>
                </div>
                <div class="col-md-2 col-sm-3 col-xs-6 itm">
                <button class="btn btn-primary itm_btn" id="itmname" onclick="insertitem('4002')">Epay</button>
                </div>
                <div class="col-md-2 col-sm-3 col-xs-6 itm">
                <button class="btn btn-primary itm_btn" id="itmname" onclick="insertitem('2')">Fees - 1st Installment</button>
                </div>


                <div class="row" style="background-color:#f5f5f5;">
                <div class="col-md-12 col-sm-12" style="padding-top:2px;">
                        <div class="col-md-6 col-sm-6" id="p_page"><button class="btn btn-primary btn-block pagenation disable" onclick="pagination(,0)"> &lt;&lt; </button></div>
                        <div class="col-md-6 col-sm-6" id="n_page"><button class="btn btn-primary btn-block pagenation" onclick="pagination(12,0)"> &gt;&gt; </button>
</div>
                    </div>
                </div>  
            </div>
```

[image]

[image]

sample js

```
    function insertitem(invcode)
        {   
            if(invcode=='')
           {
               alert("no item");
            }
    else
    {
      //some function
    }
}
```

Comment: <div class="col-md-6 col-sm-6" id="p_page"><button class="btn btn-primary btn-block pagenation disable" onclick="pagination(,0)"> &lt;&lt; </button></div>
You are missing a value in the pagination parameter.

Comment: but this is working in desktops.

Comment: my question is not about pagination button

Comment: items button not working on click in mobile devices.

Comment: But where is the js?

Comment: You have a `.row` adjacent to `.col-` classes

Comment: Have you tried the touchstart event? Not every mobile browser will automatically replace onclick handlers with ontouchstart handlers. If you have already ruled out that that is the issue, we do need more info. JS code, browser versions of where it works and where it doesn't. Does it not work on any mobile phone? Or just not on ios or android? Etc

Comment: in desktop browser when i minimize the browser size then also it is not working.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Note: Never nest col within col and cols should always be inside rows.

By the way, placing

```
<div class="clearfix"></div>
```

after the last item should clear floats and fix this issue.

Comment: I used <div class="clearfix"></div> this fixed my issue.